# Looping over an array nested within a structure

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

This is some data being returned by an API.  I need to loop over the arrays that are contained within the nested structure.  For example in the image below the savedMajorIds:

[image]

```
isArray(apiprofile.result.savedMajorIds)
```

returns Yes, so I'm pretty sure it's looking at the right thing.  However, when I try to loop over it to get the values it breaks.  Code is:

```
for (i=1, i < arrayLen(apiprofile.result.savedMajorIds),i=i+1) {
        writeOutput(apiprofile.result.savedMajorIds[i]);
    }
```

Error log doesn't like the arrayLen() portion but so far I've been unable to get that to work.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles on this:

```
(i=1, i < arrayLen(apiprofile.result.savedMajorIds),i=i+1)
```

needs to be

```
(i=1; i < arrayLen(apiprofile.result.savedMajorIds); i=i+1)
```

or

```
(i=1; i < arrayLen(apiprofile.result.savedMajorIds); i++)
```

Comment: (He replaced comma `,` with semicolon `;`.)

Comment: For future reference, you can also use the foreach-syntax: `for (id in apiprofile.result.savedMajorIds) {  }`

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options, depending on your version of ColdFusion.

```
if (isArray(apiprofile.result.savedMajorIDs)) {
    // For/In Loop on Array - Possibly CF9, Definitely CF10+ (Verify version) 
    // Note: x will leak unless var'ed inside function.
    for ( x IN apiprofile.result.savedMajorIDs ) {
        writeoutput( x & "<br>" ) ;
    }

    // ArrayEach - CF10+ > Note: y will not leak.
    ArrayEach(apiprofile.result.savedMajorIDs, function(y){writeoutput(y & "<br>");}) ;

    // Member Function .each() - CF11+  > Note: z will not leak.
    apiprofile.result.savedMajorIDs.each( function(z){writeoutput(z & "<br>");}) ;
}
```

https://trycf.com/gist/f6f3e64635e4b72da15521a3d49d485f/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: Doing some testing with various methods, the `for/in` loop seems to be significantly faster than other methods. That holds for Lists, Arrays, Structs and especially Queries.